# Implementar a função Pos no Visualg (sem usar essa função predefinida)

Tags: string, visualg, pseudocódigo

Este programa de pseudocódigo Visualg pretende implementar a função remover

Sintaxe: remover(str, indice, quantidade)

O argumento string pode ser qualquer string. O índice especifica de qual posição o número de caracteres começará a ser removido.

Exemplo: A instrução `Escrever (eliminar(str, indice, quantidade));` quando `indice` <- 13 e `quantidade` <- 3 e a variável `cad` carregada com a `Caractere` "Programação 1" deve escrever a string "Programação".

O programa compila, mas exibe exatamente o mesmo texto inserido nele

```
Algoritmo "semnome"

Var
   indice, quantidade : Inteiro
   cad, stringresultante : Caractere
   tam, i : Inteiro

Funcao remover (cad: caractere; indice, quantidade: inteiro): Caractere
inicio
  tam <- compr(cad)
  stringresultante <- ""
    // Copia el inicio de la cadena
    Para i de 1 ate quantidade faca
        stringresultante <- copia(cad,i,i)
    FimPara

    Enquanto indice <= tam Faca
        Se indice + quantidade >= tam Entao
            stringresultante <- copia(cad,indice + quantidade,indice + quantidade)
        Fimse
        indice<-indice+1;
    FimEnquanto
    Retorne cad
FimFuncao

Inicio

  Escreval("Digite a string : ")
    Leia (cad)

    Escreval("Insira a posição para iniciar a extração: ")
    Leia (indice)

    Escreval("Digite o comprimento da substring: ")
    Leia (quantidade)

    stringresultante <- remover(cad, indice, quantidade)

    Escreva (stringresultante)

Fimalgoritmo
```